# Regarding the fiware contextBroker configuration

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

In my understanding, ContextBroker provides two API models such as NGSI V1 / V2.

Regarding this options, How can I config the ContextBroker configuration?

For example:

```
Content-Type : application/json
Accep : application/json

http://example_location:1026/v1/queryContext
```

Comment: Not sure of fully understand your question, sorry... what do you mean by "config the ContextBroker configuration"? What do you mean by "to make FIWARE Service via NGSI V1 or V2"?

Comment: In my understanding, ContextBroker provides two API Model such as NGSI V1 / NGSI v2. so I would like to use two API model depending on the situation...

Comment: It means I would like to select API model through the config file... Is it possible? Thanks for your comment! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to select API version by configuration. CB supports both simultaneously so it is just a matter of "selecting" it by using the proper URL in RESTful operations:

- Those URLs starting with `/v1` belong to NGSIv1 version
- Those URLs starting with `/v2` belong to NGSIv2 version

My recommendation is use always version 2. Eventually v1 could be deprecated and removed from Orion in the future.

Maybe you find useful [the following document](https://www.slideshare.net/fermingalan/ngsiv2-overview-for-developers-that-already-know-ngsiv1) which compares NGSIv1 vs NGSIv2 and shows how the latter is much more flexible, advanced and powerful.